Labels always visible in Vue Chart JS
I'm setting up a chart in a JavaScript application using Vue.js, and I need the labels, chart information, to always be visible without needing mouse hover.
Image of a chart
The code for my chart looks like this:
<template>
  <Pie :data="ameacas.chartData" :options="ameacas.chartOptions" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js'
import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend)

export default {
  name: 'TdPie',
  components: {
    Pie
  },
  props: {
    threats: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ameacas: function () {
      return {
        chartData: {
          labels: ['Alta', 'Média', 'Baixa'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor: ['#CC092F', '#DD3820', '#FCBA03'],
              data: [this.getHighThreat, this.getMediumThreat, this.getLowThreat]
            }
          ]
        },
        chartOptions: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
      }
    },
    getHighThreat: function () {
      return this.threats
        .filter(threat => threat.severity && threat.severity.toLowerCase() == 'high')
        .length;
    },
    getMediumThreat: function () {
      return this.threats
        .filter(threat => threat.severity && threat.severity.toLowerCase() == 'medium')
        .length;
    },
    getLowThreat: function () {
      return this.threats
        .filter(threat => threat.severity && threat.severity.toLowerCase() == 'low')
        .length;
    }
  }
}
</script>

I've already tried the content from this link and others from the community.

Have you tried chartjs-plugin-datalabels?

It worked!
Thank you for the link. I didn't know how to configure a plugin, and this link helped me a lot.

I configured the "chartjs-plugin-datalabels" and the code ended up like this:


<template>
  <Pie :data="ameacas.chartData" :options="ameacas.chartOptions" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js'
import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend)
ChartJS.register(ChartDataLabels);

export default {
  name: 'TdPie',
  components: {
    Pie
  },
  props: {
    threats: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ameacas: function () {
      return {
        chartData: {
          labels: ['Alta', 'Média', 'Baixa'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor: ['#CC092F', '#DD3820', '#FCBA03'],
              data: [this.getHighThreat, this.getMediumThreat, this.getLowThreat]
            }
          ]
        },
        chartOptions: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          plugins: {
            datalabels: {
              backgroundColor: function (context) {
                return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
              },
              borderColor: 'white',
              borderRadius: 25,
              borderWidth: 2,
              color: 'white',
              padding: 6,
              formatter: Math.round
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    getHighThreat: function () {
      return this.threats
        .filter(threat => threat.severity && threat.severity.toLowerCase() == 'high')
        .length;
    },
    getMediumThreat: function () {
      return this.threats
        .filter(threat => threat.severity && threat.severity.toLowerCase() == 'medium')
        .length;
    },
    getLowThreat: function () {
      return this.threats
        .filter(threat => threat.severity && threat.severity.toLowerCase() == 'low')
        .length;
    }
  }
}
</script>



And this was the result:
New image of chart
